# How can I get the last updated data in firebase to android studio and show it in textview while the key is generated from other source

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to ask about how can I get the last updated data in Firebase, because the code:

```
dbReff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dbReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        bpm = dataSnapshot.child("bpm").getValue().toString();
        spo = dataSnapshot.child("spo2").getValue().toString();
        tempc = dataSnapshot.child("tempc").getValue().toString();
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
update();
```

I don't know how to get the data that show it like this image below because i pushed the data from a nodemcu

[image]

[image]

And I create the data inside the firebase to have more data because I need the logs to create the history page.

Edit:
The page for this code will be for this page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1aH7.jpg

re-Edit: This is the full code

```
package com.example.poxt;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class monitorFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monitor_navigation, container, false);
    }
    TextView bpmValue, spo2Value,  temperatureValue;

    int count = 0;
    String bpm, spo, tempc;
    DatabaseReference dbReff;
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        bpmValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bpmValue);
        spo2Value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spo2Value);
        temperatureValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.temperatureValue);
        dbReff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("po2t-iot-default-rtdb");
        dbReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //  Look up bpm child node
                DataSnapshot bpmSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("bpm");
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: bpmSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over child nodes of the bpm node snapshot
                    bpm = childSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("bpm", bpm); //  log the value
                }
                DataSnapshot spoSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("spo");
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: spoSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    spo = childSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("spo",spo);
                }

                //  Look up next child node
                DataSnapshot tempSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("temp");
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: tempSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over child nodes of the tempC node snapshot
                    tempc = childSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("temp",tempc);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        update();

    }
    public void update(){
        count++;
        bpmValue.setText(bpm);
        spo2Value.setText(spo);
        temperatureValue.setText(tempc);
        refresh(1000);
    }

    private void refresh(int millisecond) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                update();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, millisecond);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show all values from `bpm` you can do something like this:

```
                                                   //  Read only the bpm node
dbReff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bpm");
dbReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over child nodes of snapshot
            bpm = childSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            Log.d("bpm", bpm); //  log the value
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

If you want to process all top-level nodes like this, you can do:

```
                                                   //  Read all data
dbReff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dbReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    //  Look up bpm child node
        DataSnapshot bpmSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("bpm");
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: bpmSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over child nodes of the bpm node snapshot
            bpm = childSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            Log.d("bpm", bpm); //  log the value
        }

                                                    //  Look up next child node
        DataSnapshot tempSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("tempC");
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: tempSnapshot.getChildren()) { //  loop over child nodes of the tempC node snapshot
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand about the child in child.child(), why is it not dataSnapshot? Also I want to read other node too, so not only bpm but the other three nodes, so with the .getReferences("bpm") I cant get the other nodes, isn't that right?

Comment: Also, when I use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`, can I do it like this `getReference("bpm", "SpO2", "tempC");`?

Comment: You need to loop over the child nodes (`getChildren()`) to get at the nodes that have the actual values. I just fixed a mistake in my code, so be sure to try again.

Comment: I have try your code but it didn't show on textview, I will edit the question to show the full text code

Comment: All my code does is log the correct values: ` Log.d("bpm", bpm);`  Do those show up in your logcat output? From there, I'm honestly hoping you can take it into the text view yourself. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, I have try to do the textview by myself, but tbh, I am thought that it would just do the trick, but it is not, and I am hoping to get correction not asking for you to do the work. Anyway Thank you, and where should I go after the logcat show the output?

Comment: By the way, I have check the Logcat, it did not show the Log

Comment: Did you already step through the code (specifically the `onDataChange`) in a debugger?

Comment: No I have not, the code is the one i got from you